# Django not installing in folder where I want

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I am new to `python/django/pip`. I created a `virtualenv` and I was in the `bin` dir when I did a `pip install django`. It created the django files there which is not what I wanted. So I did `pip uninstall django`. Then I created a folder called web in my virtualenv root and tried pip install again. This time it said loading from cache and installed django in bin folder again. So I deleted it and tried again with `--no-cache-dir`. This downloaded django fresh, but I am still finding the installation in bin directory! This is driving me crazy, how can I get it to install in the web directory?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think you care where it is installed?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - because I like to be organised like that.

Comment: But what you're saying makes no sense. Your system needs files where they are supposed to go. The bin directory contains scripts like django-admin.py that are executed from the command line. The rest of the Django code goes in lib/python-x.y/site-packages/. If you tried to install it in different locations, it wouldn't be found when you tried to use it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Aha! See that is where I got it wrong. I thought django was being installed in bin because I was in that dir when I installed it first time. I thought if I was in web dir, it would install there and then make required modifications to path so that it would get found! Now I understand my misconception.

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell `pip` where to install packages. There's a standard place for packages, and that's where it installs them.

`pip` makes sure it installs utilities (such as django-admin) in the path, so when the virtual environment is activated you can run it.

Comment: Are you sure? https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-t

Comment: @ayhan - please add your comment as an answer for the benefit of others searching for the same thing!

Comment: @UndefinedVariable If this is what you are looking for, I think linking to a duplicate is better.